# To find changed data between two sql tables

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have an issue in finding the changes between to tables.

I have a 2 discount files which i have uploaded to sql database using aws redshift.

I have to find the changes in both the tables. Which discount are changed for next month.

I have prepared the query but it brings all the columns from previous month as well.

My requirement is only changed data

I have created below query

```
(select * from imtest.aws_discount_new
minus
select * from imtest.aws_discount_prev)
UNION
(select * from imtest.aws_discount_prev
minus
select * from imtest.aws_discount_new);
```

But in this data from imtest.aws_discount_prev table which is not present in imtest.aws_discount_new are also included . which needs to be excluded

```
(select * from imtest.aws_discount_new
minus
select * from imtest.aws_discount_prev)
UNION
(select * from imtest.aws_discount_prev
minus
select * from imtest.aws_discount_new);
```

Expected :  only new data from new file and data changed data prev file.

Comment: for example if new table have a data as 1 0 0 1 while previous table have the data 1 0 0 0. then result is 1 0 0 1 where it is difficult to find what is the change.
Expected result is 0 0 0 1

Comment: Current result :all records = old not changed + old changed + new 
Expected result : all records =  old changed + new

Comment: I have tried now below query , but my zero values are treated as null how to deal select t2.linked_account,t1.support_dis,t2.support_dis,
t2.support_dis-t1.support_dis "Support"

from imtest.aws_discount_new t2,
imtest.aws_discount_prev t1
where t2.linked_account(+)=t1.linked_account;

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need the first part of your query:

```
select * from imtest.aws_discount_new
minus
select * from imtest.aws_discount_prev
```

This should get "new" records, which are not in "prev".  That seems like a reasonable interpretation of what you want.

Comment: Hi Gordon ,
Thanks for your reply. But if i use only first part , i cannot identify what are the  new changes.
for example if new table have a data as 1 0 0 1   while previous table have the data  1 0 0 0.  
then result is 1 0 0 1 where it is difficult to find what is the change.

Comment: I have tried now below query , but my zero values are treated as null how to deal select t2.linked_account,t1.support_dis,t2.support_dis,
t2.support_dis-t1.support_dis "Support"

from imtest.aws_discount_new t2,
imtest.aws_discount_prev t1
where t2.linked_account(+)=t1.linked_account;